# Mysql. Should i use id?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a noob with mysql and php, and need some help :)

I have a table called "match_tabel" with "id" as the primary key (auto_increment). I put the id key in there because of performance. However, since the id will be incremented for each new match, the id will become pretty large after a while.

Matches are also deleted once they are finished.

Say there have been 100,000 matches, which are all completed (deleted from the database), the next match will then get the id "100,001" when it's created, even if it's the only row in the database.

My question is. Should I use id? 
Thanks

**EDIT**

For each match, there is a unique key. When I get a match, I search for that unique key...

Comment: What exactly help you need? What is your problem? Do you have any at all?

Comment: Yes, you should use the id and yes, it's normal behaviour that MySQL doesn't reuse numbers that you have lost by issuing a `DELETE` statement. Don't worry about running out of numbers, if you specify your `id` as `BIGINT`, it'll take a few thousand years to run out of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you always use an ID (or some other name for a primary key, typically auto-incremented). Otherwise you have no way to refer to a specific row, and no way to relate data from multiple tables.

Comment: For each match, there is a unique key. When I get a match, I search for that unique key...

Answer (score 1):

An AUTO_INCREMENT primary key is preferable to some other unique key as;

a) some other unique key will presumably be generated using PHP rather than within MySQL and so could potentially conflict with an already existing unique key (depending on how reliable your method of generating the value is), and

b) mysql_insert_id() only work for an AUTO_INCREMENT column.